# Настройка модулей в Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular2

Импортирую некоторые модули в анулар 2. Использую `system.config` и получаю ошибку `http://localhost:3000/traceur 404 not found`. Например, импорт модуля `angular2-google-maps`.

**system.config.js**

```
var map = {
  ...
 'angular2-google-maps/core': 'node_modules/angular2-google-maps/src/core',
  ...
};
var packages = {
  'angular2-google-maps/core': {
   main: 'core-module.ts', // или index.ts
   defaultExtension: 'ts'
 },
 ... 
};
```

**app/app.module.ts**

```
import { AgmCoreModule } from 'angular2-google-maps/core';
```

ошибка:

```
http://localhost:3000/traceur 404 not found
```

я так понимаю ошибка связана с компиляцией модуля, по почему она возникает? как правильно подключить модуль?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11358#issuecomment-244796194 попробуйте?

Comment: я так понимаю, что просто не тот файл подключаю. Надо везде подключать если есть umd.js файл?